# scaling mediasoup selective forwarding unit

Tags: node.js

How can mediasoup sfu be scaled up i.e how do I link 2 or more mediasoup sfu's together to pass media stream among themselves. An alternative would be ensuring that everyone in a particular room is on the same sfu server which would not be optimal. Is there a code example anywhere to do this?

Comment: Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example?*

Comment: I read in the docs that each mediasoup router can handle ~500 consumers. So why would you need multiple distinct servers when you can simply use multiple routers?

Comment: Its a good question for scaling purposes lets wait for someone to post some useful hints apart from docs

Answer (score 1):

That will be possible in mediasoup v3:

https://github.com/versatica/mediasoup/issues/227